# Erro undefined reference to std

Tags: c, c++, gcc

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int nombre, carre ;
  cout << "Introduza un numero : " ;
  cin >> nombre ;
  carre = nombre * nombre ;
  cout << "A raiz quadrada est ; " << carre ;
}
```

Quando compilo com o GCC:

> gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o calc_carre calc_carre.cpp

Obtenho:

> calc_carre.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `std::cout'
>   calc_carre.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to`
>   std::basic_ostream >&std::operator<<
>    >(std::basic_ostream >&, char const*)' calc_carre.cpp:(.text+0x1f):
>   undefined reference to `std::cin' calc_carre.cpp:(.text+0x24):
>   undefined reference to`std::istream::operator>>(int&)'
>   calc_carre.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `std::cout'
>   calc_carre.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to`
>   std::basic_ostream >&std::operator<<
>    >(std::basic_ostream >&, char const*)' calc_carre.cpp:(.text+0x4f):
>   undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
>   /tmp/cclJ9vPR.o: In function`
>   __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
>   calc_carre.cpp:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to
>   `std::ios_base::Init::Init()' calc_carre.cpp:(.text+0x8c): undefined
>   reference to`std::ios_base::Init::~Init()' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

No C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int nombre, carre ;
  printf ("Introduza un numero") ;
  scanf ("%d", &nombre) ;
  carre = nombre * nombre ;
  printf (" A sua raiz quadrada é: %d, nombre) ;
}
```

Quando compilo não obtenho nenhum erro, mas vejam pelos vossos olhos:
[image: Foto do resultado do programa]

Comment: Use #include <iostream> ou #include<stdio.h>

Comment: So nao inclui isso no stackoverflow porque o site nao deixaba mas ele esta presente

Comment: `printf ("o seu quadrado é: ...", carre)`

Comment: OK; merci, so mais uma pergunta commo posso tirar o % que aparece no fim eu vou enviar uma foto para voces verem, aqui esta o link: https://goo.gl/photos/b1imFWZyo6k2mDmu7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se está usando C++ compile com o `g++`:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o calc_carre calc_carre.cpp
```

Se quiser insisitr no `gcc`, o que não recomendo, adicone a biblioteca padrão:

```
gcc -lstdc++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o calc_carre calc_carre.cpp
```

No C tem erro também:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int nombre, carre ;
    printf("Introduza un numero");
    scanf("%d", &nombre);
    carre = nombre * nombre;
    printf("A sua raiz quadrada é: %d", carre);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9wJTwt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/skwgaifx-maniero).  Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/VariableWrong.c).

Este código obviamente não está calculando a raiz quadrada, mas aí é só matemática.

Comment: Obrigado, voce resolveu meu problema, porem no C ele nao me da a raiz quadrada et esta sempro o % presente no codigo

Comment: @MicaelAndré porque está `nombre` e o correto é `carre` como você fez no c++. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também que achar úteis. Veja o [tour].

Comment: podes ser mais especifico, esta a falar no cout ou na variável "carre" ::: carre = nombre * nombre ; Cria uma resposta com as modificaçoes no codigo por favor

Comment: @MicaelAndré editei.

Comment: Boa ideia de colocar no github

Comment: OK; merci, so mais uma pergunta commo posso tirar o % que aparece no fim eu vou enviar uma foto para voces verem, aqui esta o link: goo.gl/photos/b1imFWZyo6k2mDmu7

Comment: Como você pode ver rodando em dois lugares diferentes não aparece isto, então seu código está diferente

Comment: Sim ele esta diferente, siga as respostas dadas, mas se quiser a integralidade do codigo modificado eu envio

Comment: funciona (`-lstdc++`) se vc estiver compilando com `/usr/bin/clang++` e usando uma biblioteca statica tipo `libFuzzer.a` (`-lFuzzer`) logo apos compila-la para o FastBuild, usado na UnrealEngine.